VS code C++ Code output not showing in Terminal
So when i run a c++ code it is giving output in OUTPUT but i want it in terminal as i have to input some values so What should i do?
I tried changing the compiler but still it is not working. If anyone knows please let me know about it.

Have you tried not using code runner? It does not have a very good reputation.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist.

Then please create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it. Together with the possible output you get when building and running your program. And remember to copy-paste all text as text into your question.

Terminal support is documented by the extension:

[REPL support] To set whether to run code in Integrated Terminal (only support to run whole file in Integrated Terminal, neither untitled file nor code snippet) (default is false):
"code-runner.runInTerminal": false



Should i make it true?
